# How to apply css property on a descendent class where the parent class is being toggled?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need to apply some css on a div whose parent div's class toggles based on a class. I want to apply some css on the child div.
The parent div has classes as `.pricing-section` and `.new-pricing-section`. They are toggeled based on a flag.
The complete parent div is as follows:

```
const togglePriceSection = isPricingDetailsFeatureEnabled ? "new-pricing-section" : "pricing-section";
<div className={togglePriceSection}>
    <div className="btn btn-link btn-icon show-more-link" onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded )}>
                        {pricesList.length > 6 && !expanded ? "Show More" : expanded ? "Show Less" :null}
                    </div>
</div>
```

I want to apply css to the div with `btn` class. I was doing it like this:

```
.pricing-section, .new-pricing-section .btn.btn-link.show-more-link {
    text-transform: none;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

The problem is these properties are applied only when the parent div has `className=".new-pricing-section"`, and not when `className=".pricing-section"`. I want it to get applied in both the cases. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.pricing-section .btn.btn-link.show-more-link {
    // css if child is under pricing-section
}
.new-pricing-section .btn.btn-link.show-more-link {
    // css if child is under new-pricing-section
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The comma means this is a new selector. You actually have a bug here, it seems.

This will apply to `.pricing-section` and `.new-pricing-section .btn.btn-link.show-more-link`

```css
.pricing-section, 
.new-pricing-section .btn.btn-link.show-more-link {
    text-transform: none;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

You really want to apply to `.pricing-section .btn.btn-link.show-more-link` and `.new-pricing-section .btn.btn-link.show-more-link`

```css
.pricing-section .btn.btn-link.show-more-link, 
.new-pricing-section .btn.btn-link.show-more-link {
    text-transform: none;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

That said, it may be cleaner to separate the `new` out into an extra class. So you have the below for the button.

```css
.pricing-section .btn.btn-link.show-more-link {
    text-transform: none;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

And everything that relies on this being a `new` pricing section, you have `pricing-section new` as classList. That one you can select with `.pricing-section.new`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your selection slightly, as what you did means select the parent when it has `pricing-section` and the child when the parent has the class `new-pricing-section:

```css
.pricing-section .btn.btn-link.show-more-link, .new-pricing-section .btn.btn-link.show-more-link {
    text-transform: none;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```